# Как сделать анимацию меню?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать анимацию меню, как в шаблоне для блога **Vector** ( для Dle 9.6 ) [Демо шаблона](http://www.2dle.net/demo/96/00001/index.php?action_skin_change=yes&skin_name=vector) и можно ли сделать, анимацию постоянной с интервалом в десять секунд ?

Comment: Вы можете детально описать, что именно вы хотите получить? И какое отношение ко всему этому имеет код, приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: А что _вы_ пытались сделать для решения проблемы?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev  а вы действительно хотите помочь? Я перерыл гугл с яндексом искал все что связано с анимацией, пока что ответ не нашел, но рано или поздно найду решение.

Comment: я хочу помочь, но не собираюсь решать задачу **за** вас. Поймите, вопросы и ответы на ru.so могут и должны быть полезны не только вам лично, но и всему сообществу в целом.  А в текущей постановке, весь вопрос сводится к "_напишите код за меня_" и бесполезен для сообщества.

Comment: Нет я не хочу чтобы кто-то за меня писал код.

Comment: [jQuery Color plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/) упростит вам задачу. Да и на сайте, который вы привели в качестве примера, тоже используется данный плагин, только древней версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте используется движок DataLife Engine, а шаблон называется Vector. Скачайте шаблон и выдёргивайте скрипт.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

Единственное, что могу посоветовать в данном случае это посмотреть в сторону http://api.jquery.com/animate/ в комбинации с функцией `setInterval`